# Structures and memory management, C

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

I'm trying to understand some things about structures and memory management. I have three versions code whose result is identical. They only differ in the definition/allocation of the structure. In version one, the structure is allocated with this code: `resultValue_t *resultVal = malloc(sizeof(resultValue_t));`. In version two, the structure is created inside the function: `resultValue_t resultVal;`. In version three `resultValue_t resultVal;` is created globally.
I would like to ask how the three definitions actually differ? Which one gives which possibilities? And which one is more appreciated?
I know that if a structure is accessed via a pointer, the `->` operator should be used, etc. But here I'm curious about the difference and possibilities between these definitions.

//version_1

```
typedef struct
{
    int valOne;
    int valTwo;
}resultValue_t;

void twoSum(int *array, int sum)
{
    int baseVal, tempSum;
    int arrLen = sizeof(array);
  
    resultValue_t *resultVal = malloc(sizeof(resultValue_t));
    
    //...
    if (tempSum == sum)
    {
        resultVal->valOne = array[index];
        resultVal->valTwo = array[nIndex];
        printf("%d + %d\n", resultVal->valOne, resultVal->valTwo);
    }
    //...

    free(resultVal);
}
```

//version_2

```
typedef struct
{
    int valOne;
    int valTwo;
}resultValue_t;

void twoSum2(int *array, int sum)
{
    int baseVal, tempSum;
    
    resultValue_t resultVal;
    
    //...
    if (tempSum == sum)
    {
        resultVal.valOne = array[index];
        resultVal.valTwo = array[nIndex];
        printf("%d + %d\n", resultVal.valOne, resultVal.valTwo);
    }
    //...
}
```

//version_3

```
typedef struct
{
    int valOne;
    int valTwo;
}resultValue_t;
resultValue_t resultVal;
```

Comment: For the record, it's better to typedef your structs like this `typedef struct resultValue_t {...} resultValue_t;` so that you can add another resultValue_t struct as its variable (for example to create linked lists)

Comment: Variant 1 usually is *not* recommendable. If you need the struct only within the function keep it with local storage duration (so variant 2) *unless* it is of such large size that you need to fear stack overflow. Variant 3 is not thread-safe. If you are single-threaded anyway, though, it can be (in case of large struct) a valid alternative to variant 1 to spare dynamic memory allocation (thus improving performance).

Comment: OT: This code `int arrLen = sizeof(array);` is .... hmm... Well, you never us `arrLen` so it's hard to say what you expect but ... from the name `arrLen` it seems you expect something that the code isn't doing. Just to warn :-)

Comment: @4386427 yes yes I know that :) this is only part of the code that is in this function

Comment: @MrmDdda And you are aware that **the code does not** give you the length of the array!? It gives you the size of a pointer (typically 4 or 8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is "storage duration", i.e. the lifetime of object.

In version 1 "allocated storage duration" is used. That means that the object `resultVal` exists after `malloc` returns and until some code explicit "kills it" by calling `free`. On most systems memory is allocated in an area called heap. The allocation is typically slow (i.e. don't use it unless there is a good reason - see later).

In version 2 "automatic storage duration" is used. That means that the object `resultVal` exists until execution of the associated block ends. In this case until the function returns. In other words - in this case the object `resultVal` is automatically created when execution enters the function and automatically destroyed when execution leaves the function.
On most systems memory is allocated in an area called stack. The allocation is typically very fast.

In version 3 "static storage duration" is used. That means that the object `resultVal` exists from execution start to execution end. So the object can be accessed at any time from anywhere in the code. Memory is typically allocated in some special area as part of program start up and it's also very fast.

Obviously there are use cases for all 3 types.

Version 3 shall in general be avoided but there are special cases where static objects make sense. When used it's typically good to limit their use to "file scope" using the keyword `static`.

In most cases you should go for version 2 as it is fast and secure. However, if the size of the object (in this case `resultVal`) is very big, version 2 should be avoided due to risk of stack overflow. In that case use version 1.

Version 1 is also useful (actually required) if you want the object to be "alive" after the function returns. That however is not the case for the example in the question as `free` is called before leaving the function.

Conclusion:

Since `resultValue_t;` is a rather small object type and the object `resultVal` doesn't need to be "alive" after the function call, you should go for version 2.

Comment: Thanks @4386427. For version 3, would it be a good example to use when building an interface? There we need access to the structure basically from many places in the code being built. Versions 1 and 2 are already heavily dependent on what we are coding.

Comment: @MrmDdda Yes, that is one example where version 3 can be accepted. If you implement a number of function to be called from "other files" and these functions  need to share some data that you want to hide from the user of the functions, you can make a file scope static variable so that all functions inside your code can use the object but no one outside can access it. But just to repeat... think twice before using version 3.

Comment: Re “exists until the execution leaves the scope”: Per the C standard, the object exists until execution of the associated block **ends**, not until execution **leaves** the block. Calling a subroutine causes execution to leave the block, but execution of the block is only suspended, not ended, so the object continues to exist and may be used during this time (e.g., via a pointer passed to the subroutine).

Comment: Re “automatically destroyed when execution leaves the function”: That is true in this case, except for the “leaves” versus “ends” issue above, but, more generally, where a definition appears inside a nested block, the lifetime ends when execution of the associated block ends, which may be earlier than when execution of the function ends.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the advice regarding the wording. I tried to edit the answer accordingly. BTW: Feel free to update the answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

- Version 1 allocates memory from the heap.
- Version 2 allocates memory from the stack.
- Version 3 uses memory from the bss section (In every compiler implementation I've used, but it could come from elsewhere). It's also the only version that initializes the object (in this case, to all zeroes).